# redirect a page to already redirect directory

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have **www.example.com** and **booking.example.com** and I want to redirect **booking.example.com/partners** to **example.com/partners**.

I'm currently using

```
location ~ ^/partners/(.*) {
    return 301 http://www.example.com/partners/$1;
}
```

but now I want to redirect an old defunct link to a new one, for example, **booking.example.com/partners/doesntexist** to **www.example.com/partners/doesexist**

I tried to do this:

```
location  "^/partners/IDoNotExistAnymore" {
    return 301 http://www.example.com/partners/CorrectLink;
}
```

But it doesn't work, it always redirects to route.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the syntax of the `location` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

You seem to be using regular expression locations, but prefix locations and exact match locations will be more efficient in this case:

```
location ^~ /partners {
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
location = /partners/IDoNotExistAnymore {
    return 301 http://www.example.com/partners/CorrectLink;
}
```